# Extract column name and match with another column

Tags: r, filtering

I have a dataframe `MutationsNumberTable` like this

```
    ACC BLCA BRCA CESC   HGNC
1:   1    2    6    0   OPN4
2:   2    3    1    1  KLRB1
3:   2   23    4    5  SALL2
4:   1    8    5    7  PLCB2
```

The goal is to create a matrix where I have unique pairs "gene-cancer type" where a number in a table is greater than a threshold (let's say, 5):

Desired output:

```
     HGNC Cancer
1:   OPN4 CESC
2:   SALL2 BRCA
3:   SALL2 CESC
4:   PLCB2 BLCA 
5:   PLCB2 BRCA 
6:   PLCB2 CESC
```

So far, I could come up with this:

```
n = ncol(MutationsNumberTable)
whereTrue = MutationsNumberTable[,1:(n-1)] >=threshold
```

but I have difficulties after to use these logical values to make a matrix I need. I tried

```
colnames(whereTrue)[whereTrue]
```

but it is not exactly what I need.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

We can do a `gather` to 'long' format and then `filter`

```
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)
gather(df1, Cancer, val, -HGNC) %>%
     filter(val >= 5) %>%
     select(-val)
```

---

Or using `data.table`

```
library(data.table)
setDT(df1)[, melt(.SD, id.var = 'HGNC')[value >= 5, .(HGNC, Cancer = variable)]]
```

Comment: `data.table` worked perfectly well, thanks a lot! But gather function gives an error: Error in select(., -val) : unused argument (-val).

Comment: @lizaveta  May be `select` from another package is masking.  Can you try `%>% dplyr::select(-val)`